# When were the SUVAT equations derived for the first time?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

It's one of the first things learned in Physics.

However, what's the history behind deriving the SUVAT equations?

And, there were other equivalent equations used before SUVAT came into the curriculum?

Comment: I had to google “SUVAT equations” to find what this is, which appears to be a relatively recently used acronyme for the various equations of motion for constant acceleration. The google search [history + kinematics + motion + acceleration](https://www.google.com/search?q=history+kinematics+motion+acceleration) will be helpful. It led me to [this seemingly helpful blog essay](https://blog.scienceborealis.ca/exploring-the-history-of-the-math-of-motion/) and [this advanced historical monograph](https://ir.uiowa.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=iihr_monograph_series). **(continued)**

Comment: I personally never really learned the equations I see in non-calculus based physics texts, since you can get all you need by trivial integrations of “accel = const” (once for velocity, twice for distance), and anything else you might need can be taken care of by simple (and not tricky) algebra from these two. Of course, after you do this 3 or 4 times, you tend to remember $s = s_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2,$ so I usually just wrote this down and then differentiated to get velocity, and the rest was algebra using these two equations.

Comment: They are basic applications of calculus and have probably been repeatedly derived from the days of Newton.  I don't think a meaningful answer is possible here.

Comment: I agree with @Mary. Besides, the acronym SUVAT is recent, and only used in English :  forging acronysms like this one for didactic purposes (?) is a disease of our times...

Comment: The acronym is recent, the substance goes back to middle ages, see [mean speed theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_speed_theorem), and [Galileo](http://cerebro.xu.edu/math/math147/02f/galileo/galileo3rdday.html). In more or less modern form the formulas were written by [Euler](https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1806-11172017000400701&lng=pt&nrm=iso&tlng=en).